# jquery prepend movendo pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou com uma div que contem varias listas (uls) de um box, em cada box tem uma imagem e uma descrição.
estou implementando um rolamento infinito para cima da seguinte forma:

- O usuario acessa uma pagina especifica (ex pagina 6), cada pagina tem 5 uls.
- quando a pagina é rolada para cima uma nova pagina é carregada por ajax, trazendo mais 5 uls e sendo inserida no html por um prepend.

Antes do carregamento a primeira ul tinha a id 'ul30', depois do carregamento a primeira ul tem a id 'ul25'.

Quando dou o prepend a pagina rola a tela até a ul25. Como posso fazer para manter a posição original (ul30)?

*Obs: tentei fazer uma animação usando o $().animate() no final do success do ajax para a ul30, mas como os box tem imagens, que demoram um pouco pra carregar, a posição passada para o animate ainda não é a posição final (o browser ainda está montando a pagina) então fica em uma posição entre a ul25 e a ul30

*Obs2: não posso botar um tamanho fixo para as imagens via css, mesmo tendo um padrão de tamanho de imagens cadastradas (estas podem vir a ter o tamanho alterado posteriormente)

**[EDIT]**

Em exemplo da implementação que quero fazer é o facebook, quado está na timeline e novas historias são carregadas, não é alterada a posição da tela, mas um conteúdo html é inserido no inicio do elemento da timeline.

Comment: precisaria de horas pra recriar toda a estrutura, não vou conseguir criar :/

Answer (score 0):

Pilati, uma solução simples para o seu caso, é pular para o elemento atual.

```
var url = location.href;               //Armazene a URL sem o #
var topo = "ul30";                     //id do elemento que você quer exibir no topo
location.href = "#" + topo;            //Para mover o scroll para o elemento desejado.
history.replaceState(null,null,url);   //removendo o # da URL.
```

Comment: o replaceState com hash não altera a posição da tela no meu site, e mesmo assim daria o problema das imagens irem carregando e o tamanho da pagina carregada tambem mudando, tirando o elemento ul30 da tela